# Display in node.js to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```js
let request = require('request');

let cheerio = require('cheerio');

const $url = 'http://kradata.kra.co.kr:8082/service/api15/getOpenDataList';

const $KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const $meet = '1';

const $hr_no = '037703';

const $api_url = $url + '?meet=' + $meet + '&hr_no=' + $hr_no + '&ServiceKey=' + $KEY;

console.log($api_url);



request($api_url, function(err, res, body) {

    $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('item').each(function(idx){

        let no1 = $(this).find('hrName').text();

        let no2 = $(this).find('winRateT').text();

        let no3 = $(this).find('qnlRateT').text();

        let no4 = $(this).find('winRateY').text();

        let no5 = $(this).find('recentRcDist').text();

        let no6 = $(this).find('chaksunT').text();

        let no7 = $(this).find('chaksunY').text();

        let no8 = $(this).find('chaksun_6').text();



        console.log(`경주마 이름 : ${no1} \n 통산 승률: ${no2}, 통산 복승률: ${no3}, 최근 1년 승률: ${no4} \n 최근경주거리: ${no5}, 통산착순상금: ${no6}, 최근1년착순상금: ${no7}, 최근6개월수득상금: ${no8}`);             

 });});
```

How can I show the data in console.log in html?

Comment: Please don't add spam text to your question to get around the non-code character requirement - instead, explain your problem more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the text you're `console.log()`ing, which I believe is this:

```
console.log(`경주마 이름 : ${no1} \n 통산 승률: ${no2}, 통산 복승률: ${no3}, 최근 1년 승률: ${no4} \n 최근경주거리: ${no5}, 통산착순상금: ${no6}, 최근1년착순상금: ${no7}, 최근6개월수득상금: ${no8}`);
```

Then just add a `document.write()` call:

```
document.write(`경주마 이름 : ${no1} \n 통산 승률: ${no2}, 통산 복승률: ${no3}, 최근 1년 승률: ${no4} \n 최근경주거리: ${no5}, 통산착순상금: ${no6}, 최근1년착순상금: ${no7}, 최근6개월수득상금: ${no8}`);
```

This will replace the current text on the page with the items you are `console.log()`ing.

Comment: I think he meant to display HTML inside console, using console.log.

Comment: The exact words were *"How can I show the data in console.log in html?"*, which I interpreted as "How can I show the data I am logging to the console on the HTML page as well?".